# Reading data from a remote database

Tags: vb.net

How to read data, submit queries from vb application to a remote machine running sql server.

**Please note:** I have created a complete functional version of a stock control system with   the database residing in the local machine. I just need the basic concept of interacting with remote databases that's all. Do we have to use sockets to read/send data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is change your connection string to the remote db server and make sure that the server is [actually listening](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277). (Link assumes 2005 but 2k, 2k8+ config will be similar and easily Googled for...) You definitely DO NOT have to write special code for this.

Check out http://connectionstrings.com/ for a handy reference for the different types of connection strings in different situations.

Answer (score 0):

Are we talk about .NET version of VB or old fashioned VB 6?
In .NET version of VB (VB.NET) you can use OLEDB Data adapter, ODBC Data Adapter or native .NET Data adapter depends on your needs.
See MSDN documentation [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08.aspx)
In VB6 version, you can use ADO, OLEDB or ODBC. See documentation here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa968814(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa968814%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
I don;t recommendate to connect your application via socket by yourself because this is really bloody coding.